# Problems with Iron Router and function computation + template rendering

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an issue with a template rendering before my subscription is received from server + computation function calculates the necessary data to actually render it. Sometimes, it works fine and the process first subscribes to the MongoDB, renders my `computeValues()` function and then loads the template. When I try the same thing again, the template renders before the actual data is calculated and results in the below error:

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length'
>   of undefined

That obviously tells me that the `computeValues()` function ran without getting data from my subscription, where it went through an empty DB and couldn't do the calculation properly.

Here is the Iron:Router code:

```
Router.route("/management/bankroll", {
subscriptions: function(){
  return Meteor.subscribe("bank");
},
action: function(){
this.wait(computeValues());

if(this.ready()){
  this.layout("bankroll");
} else{
  this.layout("loading");
}
},
name: "bankroll"
});
```

I tried all kinds of hooks like onBeforeAction, I used .wait()...pretty much anything and the behavior is still the same. One instance, the upload works and the template rendering waits until data is pulled like it's supposed to, and if I try it again, the compute function runs before subscription is received.

I have also used waitOn for the subscription and that doesn't work either.
It's basically the template renders before the computeValues function does the calculation due to not being able to retrieve the subscription in time. This happens more often in larger files where retrieving the subscription takes longer.

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: What does `computeValues()` do? Have you tried putting it in `Template.bankroll.onRendered()` instead of inside the router?

Comment: computeValues takes in JSON data that was converted from an Excel file and sorts them into variables and objects, which are then displayed on the template.

Comment: It's basically the template renders before the computeValues function does the calculation due to not being able to retrieve the subscription in time. This happens more often in larger files where retrieving the subscription takes longer.

Comment: I'd also suggest trying the onRendered callback.  Try the pattern shown [here](http://danblog.io/meteor-tips-and-workarounds/) in the section `Don’t render until ready`

Comment: I tried putting it into onRendered and it won't even show the computations anymore.

Comment: Since `computeValues()` is creating the route's data, why not run it in a `data:` handler in your route instead of `action:`. It will automatically wait for `waitOn:` to finish. You might also show some of your `computeValues()` code because there could be something in there that's affecting what's going on.